# SQL where field in vs. where field = with multiple ors?

Tags: sql, syntax

Which of these is better to use in regard to performance? ...in regard to readability / understandability? ...in regard to accepted standards?

```
SELECT *
FROM Wherever
WHERE Greeting IN ('hello', 'hi', 'hey')
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM Wherever
WHERE Greeting = 'hello' 
   OR Greeting = 'hi'
   OR Greeting = 'hey'
```

The first seems more intuitive / clear to me, but I'm unsure of accepted standards and performance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It more readable, and more universally accepted to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Wherever
WHERE Greeting in ('hello', 'hi', 'hey')
```

All modern SQL servers optimize your queries, so they're both likely to be changed into the same code that runs on the server, so performance differences will be negligible or non-existent.

**Edit:**

Apparently the `in` option is faster, as it evaluates to a binary lookup, whereas the multiple `=` just evaulates each statement individually.

Comment: I'm not sure about it being more acceptable, but the grammar of the IN is certainly more readable. Look at "greeting is in this list" compared to "greeting is this or greeting is that or greeting is some other thing"

Answer (score 7):

All major engines (`MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle` and `SQL Server`) will optimize it to exactly same plans.

Answer (score 4):

Performance = identical.

Readability = "IN"

Answer (score 0):

I would say the first option involving `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Wherever
WHERE Greeting IN ('hello', 'hi', 'hey')
```

It is:

- much faster
- easier to read
- no need to use multiple `or`
- less typing
- easier to maintain in big queries
- widely used

**More Stuff:**

**[SQL IN Directive Much Faster Than Multiple OR Clauses](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/174-SQL-IN-Directive-Much-Faster-Than-Multiple-OR-Clauses.htm)**

Comment: That link is not comparing like for like at the SQL level. It's comparing CF looping/value list performance

Comment: The `OR`-concatenated query is wrong in the link, as someone had pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The IN version is much clearer and, since it's a single term, avoids the possibility of missing or incorrectly structured parentheses if you add other terms to the WHERE clause.

In addition, I believe that more SQL implementations will optimize the IN version assuming that an index is available.