# Is there any performance difference between a SQL "IN" statement versus using "OR"?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Thought I would ask the knowledgeable StackOverflow community a question that was on my mind today and I can't seem to find an answer.

Is there any performance difference or advantage between an "IN" or using "OR"?

Ie. Is

**SELECT type FROM types WHERE typecat IN ('abc', 'def')**

better than

**SELECT type FROM types WHERE typecat = 'abc' OR typecat = 'def'**

*Adding*: Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What server? SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle...?

Comment: I once asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343242/sql-where-field-in-vs-where-field-with-multiple-ors

Comment: Sorry, using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks Froadie, there were some mixed comments, but I do believe the optimizer creates identical queries from the majority of responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, SQL Server converts the `IN` statement you have into the `OR` statement.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely on the SQL product you're using, which you haven't stated.  One RDBMS that I use regularly cannot use indexes for the OR version.

Comment: Care to reveal the name of said RDBMS?

Comment: R:Base (blast from the past).

Comment: Sorry, using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no performance difference. The optimizer takes care of it.